# Unable to connect Kafka using camel

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, strimzi

We are using camel kafka component to connect to the Kafka cluster. I am seeing the below errors when my application starts. Can you please help me what these errors mean. I am sure that the client is not able to connect to the bootstrap server. I have purposefully masked the bootstrap server ip and port

```
2020-09-03 10:02:39.936+05:30 WARN  [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker x.x.x.x:nnnn (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2020-09-03 10:02:41.613+05:30 WARN  [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker x.x.x.x:nnnn (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2020-09-03 10:02:43.456+05:30 WARN  [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker x.x.x.x:nnnn (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2020-09-03 10:02:45.066+05:30 WARN  [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker x.x.x.x:nnnn (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2020-09-03 10:02:46.932+05:30 WARN  [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker x.x.x.x:nnnn (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

My software levels are

- CAMEL : 3.1.0
- Kafka Client : 2.5.0

Kafka Cluster levels

- Strimzi -0.18.0
- Kafka : 2.5.0

Comment: Could it be this SSL issue that another user was having?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717835/unable-to-connect-kafka-using-camel

Comment: Is there any more information? Does the application actually fail to send/receive from Kafka? Are there details exceptions when it does? Is the communication over SSL? If so, it might be useful to enable -Djavax.net.debug=ssl on the client.

Comment: yes, it turned out to be that I missed to disable SSL on the kafka broker.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved with the hint from [Karl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14172230/karl). I had to re-deploy the Kafka with tls: false. Since this is dev environment. It is Ok to do so